# How to run Skype after installing it using AUR package on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, skype

I have installed Skype using the AUR package following these steps:

```
wget https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/skypeforlinux-bin.tar.gz
tar zxf skypeforlinux-bin.tar.gz
cd skypeforlinux-bin
makepkg -s
```

And the output was:

```
==> Making package: skypeforlinux-bin 8.6.76.56247-1 (Fri Sep  8 10:11:48 -03 2017)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Found skypeforlinux_8.6.76.56247_amd64.deb
==> Validating source files with sha256sums...
    skypeforlinux_8.6.76.56247_amd64.deb ... Passed
==> Extracting sources...
  -> Extracting skypeforlinux_8.6.76.56247_amd64.deb with bsdtar
==> Removing existing $pkgdir/ directory...
==> Entering fakeroot environment...
==> Starting package()...
==> Tidying install...
  -> Removing libtool files...
  -> Purging unwanted files...
  -> Removing static library files...
  -> Stripping unneeded symbols from binaries and libraries...
  -> Compressing man and info pages...
==> Checking for packaging issue...
==> Creating package "skypeforlinux-bin"...
  -> Generating .PKGINFO file...
  -> Generating .BUILDINFO file...
  -> Generating .MTREE file...
  -> Compressing package...
==> Leaving fakeroot environment.
==> Finished making: skypeforlinux-bin 8.6.76.56247-1 (Fri Sep  8 10:13:39 -03 2017)
```

Now, how can I run Skype? because I've tried searching for the command `skype` or similar, but nothing appeared.

Could you help me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The simplest thing to do is list the files in the package - see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Tips_and_tricks#Listing_files_owned_by_a_package_with_size . You'll normally want the one in `/usr/bin`. And the command might be `skypeforlinux`. That's what it's here.

Comment: @FaheemMitha won't work as it is not installed: pacman knows nothing about it.

Comment: @jasonwryan Yes, I see. But it's customary to install programs before trying to run them, so I thought he had. Pardon my assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have built the package (`makepkg -s`), but you haven't installed it, so obviously you cannot run it.

`pacman -Q skypeforlinux-bin` will confirm that it is not installed.

The `makepkg` output also makes this evident:

> ==> Finished making: skypeforlinux-bin 8.6.76.56247-1 (Fri Sep  8 10:13:39 -03 2017)

As the [wiki page on the AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository#Build_and_install_the_package) makes clear, you need to pass `makepkg -i` to install your built package.

At this point, you can either rebuild, or simpler providing you still have the built package, just use pacman:

```
sudo pacman -U $package_name.pkg.tar.xz
```

Comment: Please note, as I found out when yaourt wasn't updating Skype that the file names have changed, the main one is now `skypeforlinux-stable-bin`.  You'll get a `skypeforlinux-stable-bin and skypeforlinux-bin are in conflict (skypeforlinux). Remove skypeforlinux-bin? [y/N]` message when installing.